# Allowing ActiveXObject for a trusted site

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, prompt, activexobject

I've had an idea that would greatly improve the intranet homepage at an organisation, but this idea needs activexobject. During testing, I've been unable to disable the prompt asking for confirmation on whether to run the control. How can I overcome this?

(The Organisation only uses IE, 8 in some places, but mostly 9)

All help appreciated

Comment: Every user's machine need to be configured to get the homepage on the Trusted Sites list.  Control Panel + Internet Options + Security tab.  Leave this up to IT staff, they are liable to have an opinion about it.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried allowing the site via the settings, but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

**Please follow below steps to disable opening of ActiveX prompt for allowing to run.**

ActiveX controls are essentially mini-programs that can be shared by different Windows applications.

Note: ActiveX controls are the most common tools for loading viruses, spyware and other malicious software onto computers. Because of this, every time a website tries to install an ActiveX control, Internet Explorer asks you whether you want to allow it. These prompts can prevent harm to your computer

Follow the steps mentioned below to disable the ActiveX prompts.

1. Click on Internet explorer icon to open Internet explorer.
2. Click on Tools and then select Internet Options form the list.
3. Click on the Security tab and click on Custom Level button.
4. This opens a "Security Settings" window with a list of actions that could compromise yourcomputer's security. For each one, you can tell Explorer to automatically block the action in all instances ("Disable"), allow it in all instances ("Enable") or ask you whether to block it ("Prompt").
5. Scroll down to the section marked "ActiveX Controls and Plug-ins.
6. Select  "Enable" for the following actions:

a.      "Allow previously unused ActiveX controls to run without prompt"

b.     "Download signed ActiveX controls"

c.      "Download unsigned ActiveX controls"

d.     "Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe for scripting"

e.     "Run ActiveX controls and plug-ins"

f.       "Script ActiveX controls marked safefor scripting."

1. Select  "Disable" for the action "Automatic prompting for ActiveX controls."
2. Click "OK" to close the Security Settings window, then "OK" again to close the Internet Options window.
3. Restart your computer,the new security settings are in effect, and you should no longer see ActiveX prompts.

**If you are unable to understand any point, let me know i will guide you through.**